# How to convert NSDateComponents to NSDate?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I have this function :

```
private func getCurrentDateComponent() -> NSDateComponents {
        let date = NSDate()
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: date)
        return components
    }
```

When I call it and I use the function `date`

```
var d = this.getCurrentDateComponent().date
```

I don't know why the variable d is nil...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how I do it:

```
let allUnits = NSCalendarUnit(rawValue: UInt.max)
return UICalendar.currentCalendar().components(allUnits, fromDate: NSDate())
```

Note that in Swift 2.0 the bitwise OR operator `|` is not used any more, instead the `NSCalendarUnit` conforms to the `OptionSetType` format:

```
let timeUnits : NSCalendarUnit = [.Hour, .Minute, .Second]
```

Answer (score 22):

**Swift 4 :**

```
let date = NSCalendar.current.date(from: components) 

// components is your component name
```

Answer (score 1):

The conversion between a *date* and  *date components* always requires a *calendar*. 
You have two options (compare [NSCalendar dateFromComponents: vs NSDateComponents date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108932/nscalendar-datefromcomponents-vs-nsdatecomponents-date)):

- Assign a calendar to the date components, i.e. add

  ```
  components.calendar = calendar
  ```

  to your `getCurrentDateComponent()` method. Then

  ```
  var d = getCurrentDateComponent().date
  ```

  works as expected. (Without assigning  a calendar to the date
  components, the `date` property returns `nil`, as you observed.)
- Alternatively, call a calendar method for the conversion:

  ```
  let d = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(getCurrentDateComponent())
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the calendar before using `NSDateComponents`, because without calendar there in no date.

```
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: date)
components.calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar();
return components
```